# Make code more Generic in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, enumeration, solid-principles

I have a **Trigger Manager** scenario where I **delegate** the **triggers** (in other-words subscribe triggers) to different **handlers**.

For now I have three handler types, I use a **switch-case** with **enum** (enum here is the handler type) to redirect to correct handler.

But my code seems not extensible, its not generic and it doesn't follow **SOLID** principle. Imagine if I need to have more handler

**I will be eventually coming and editing my switch case code and I will have more cases where it affects the cyclomatic complexity of my code**

Below is my exact code snippet

```
private static TriggerContext getTriggerContext(TriggerHandlerType triggerHandlerType) throws TriggerHandlerException {
    switch (triggerHandlerType) {
        case DASHBOARD_HANDLER:
            triggerContext = new TriggerContext(new DashboardTriggerHandler());
            return triggerContext;
        case COMPONENT_HANDLER:
            triggerContext = new TriggerContext(new ComponentTriggerHandler());
            return triggerContext;
        case WIDGET_HANDLER:
            triggerContext = new TriggerContext(new WidgetTriggerHandler());
            return triggerContext;
        default:
            LOGGER.error(MIS_CONFIGURED_REQUEST_IS_PROVIDED);
            throw new TriggerHandlerException(TRIGGER_HANDLER_TYPE_GIVEN_IS_NOT_CONFIGURED_IN_THE_LIST_OF_TRIGGER_HANDLERS);

    }

}
```

Can someone help me to enhance this code in-which I can make it more generic and avoid cyclomatic complexity and follow **SOLID** Principle along with some **design pattern**.

Comment: This is a question for Stack Exchange Code Review

Comment: Look into a Strategy Pattern.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: You could add a `createTrigger()` factory  method on the Enum instances, and just call it like `triggerHandlerType.createTrigger()`. Or one step even more formal: you could create a `TriggerFactory` interface, that you would implement with the Enum, and use that type whenever possible.

Comment: This is *too broad*. There are *a lot* of ways to make this code more extendable. Maybe look into a good book like "Design patterns" from the Gang of Four?

Comment: I think you should have one TriggerManager for each type of data it's to handle.  Make subclasses to handle each specific data type.  (Then look at the Trampoline pattern for the opposite idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "*make code more dynamic*", and your problem comes from using objects as primitives.

Rather than switching on the enum object, your enum objects should contain the type to be instantiated:

```
enum TriggerHandlerType {
    DASHBOARD {
        @Override
        TriggerHandler create() {
            return new DashboardTriggerHandler();
        }
    },
    COMPONENT_HANDLER {
        //...
    };

    abstract TriggerHandler create();
}
```

`getTriggerContext` can then call `create()` to instantiate the handler:

```
private static TriggerContext getTriggerContext(TriggerHandlerType triggerHandlerType) throws TriggerHandlerException {
    return new TriggerContext(triggerHandlerType.create());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the overall design structure, but the switch can be replaced with a `newHandler()` method on the enum.

```
private static TriggerContext getTriggerContext(TriggerHandlerType triggerHandlerType)
    throws TriggerHandlerException
{
    return new TriggerContext(triggerHandlerType.newHandler());
}
```

In the enum you [would implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413872/can-an-enum-have-abstract-methods) the method for each type enum as

```
enum TriggerHandlerType {
    DASHBOARD_HANDLER
    {
        Handler newHandler() { return new DashboardHandler(); }
    },
    ...;
    abstract Handler newHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map of configurations for that:

```
// All your triggers classes should implement this interface
interface TriggerHandler {}

// For example:
public static class DashboardTriggerHandler implements TriggerHandler {
}

// Create your configuration
static Map<TriggerHandlerType, Class> contexts;
static {
    contexts = new HashMap<>();
    contexts.put(TriggerHandlerType.DASHBOARD_HANDLER, DashboardTriggerHandler.class);
    contexts.put(TriggerHandlerType.COMPONENT_HANDLER, ComponentTriggerHandler.class);
    contexts.put(TriggerHandlerType.WIDGET_HANDLER, WidgetTriggerHandler.class);
}

// Return your instance through reflection
public static TriggerContext getTriggerContext(TriggerHandlerType triggerHandlerType) throws TriggerHandlerException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    Class className = contexts.get(triggerHandlerType);

    if (className == null) {
        throw new TriggerHandlerException();
    }

    return new TriggerContext((TriggerHandler)className.newInstance());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer it directed me in the correct path!