# The right and wrong approach to writing Java Enums

Tags: java, enums

Recently, I've discovered this code of the following structure:

*Interface*:

```
public interface Base<T> {

    public T fromValue(String v);

}
```

*Enum implementation*:

```
public enum AddressType implements Base<AddressType> {

    NotSpecified("Not Specified."),

    Physical("Physical"),

    Postal("Postal");

    private final String label; 

    private AddressType(String label) { 
        this.label = label; 
    } 

    public String getLabel() { 
        return this.label; 
    }

    @Override
    public AddressType fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }
}
```

My immediate reaction is that one cannot create an instance of an enum by deserialization or by reflection, so the `fromValue()` should be static.

I'm not trying to start a debate, but is this correct? I have read, [Why would an Enum implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709593/why-would-an-enum-implement-an-interface), and I totally agree with the answers provided, but the above example is invalid.

I am doing this because the "architect" doesn't want to take my answer, so this is to create a strong argument (with facts) why the above approach is good/bad.

Comment: Besides enums, are there other classes implementing the interface?

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo, nope. Only interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Base` interface does not declare `valueOf` and the `fromValue` method is indeed implemented. I see no reason why this code should not compile. If you are referring to the `valueOf` call inside `fromValue`, that is a call of a static method defined for every enum. I would have to agree, though, that the design of it is quite misguided as you need an arbitrary member of the enum just to call `fromValue` and get the real member.

On the other hand, in a project that I'm doing right now I have several enums implementing a common interface. This because the enums are related and I want to be able to treat them uniformly with respect to their common semantics.

Comment: Sweet, thanks... I mixed the `fromValue` and `valueOf`, but the other argument still stands.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this design is wrong. In order to use `valueFrom()` one has to get an instance of this enum beforehand. Thus, it will look like:

```
AddressType type = AddressType.Postal.valueFrom("Physical");
```

What sense does it make?

Answer (score 0):

Your Base interface seems to serve a whole other purpose (if any).

It is probably meant to be a String-to-T-converter, since it generates a T from a String. The `enum` is simply wrong if it implements this interface (@yegor256 already pointed out why). So you can keep the enum and you can have some `AddressTypeConverter implements Base<AddressType>` which calls `AddressType.valueOf()` in its `fromString()` method.

But don't get me wrong: enums implementing interfaces are NOT a bad practice, it's just this particular usage that is completely wrong.