# How to return an instance from Enum?

Tags: java, enums

Consider that I have `Algorithm` enum as

```
public enum Algorithm {
  SHA1("sha1"),
  HMAC("hmac"),;

  Algorithm(final String algorithm) {
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
  }
  private final String algorithm;

  public String getAlgorithm() {
    return algorithm;
  }
}
```

and I have different algorithms as

```
public class Sha1 {
   public static String hash(final String text, final byte[] sb) {...}
}
```

and

```
public class Hmac {
   public static String hash(final String text, final byte[] sb) {...}
}
```

I want to return their instances when someone calls for example

```
Algorithm.SHA1.getInstance()
```

**Question**

- How can I return the instance since my method is static? (It is static so that multiple threads can not play around with each other data)

Comment: To making it thread safe - what about using synchronization?

Comment: The same way you add a getAlgorithm() method you can also add a getInstance() method. You can implement that on the Enum or on the different ciphers. `SHA1("sha1") { X getInstance() { return new Sha1(); }, Hmac("hmac") { X getInstance() { return new Hmac(); }` (but that does not help you much with a static method - which is not a good idea in that case anyway).

Answer (score 6):

You can't return an instance when your method is static, but [you can make your `enum` implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709831/335858), and make an instance method that calls the static method perform the virtual dispatch for you:

```
public interface EncryptionAlgo {
    String hash(final String text, final byte[] sb);
}

public enum Algorithm implements EncryptionAlgo {
    SHA1("sha1") {
        public String hash(final String text, final byte[] sb) {
            return Sha1.hash(text, sb);
        }
    },
    HMAC("hmac") {
        public String hash(final String text, final byte[] sb) {
            return Hmac.hash(text, sb);
        }
    };

    Algorithm(final String algorithm) {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }
    private final String algorithm;

    public String getAlgorithm() {
        return algorithm;
    }
}
```

Now you can call `hash` on the `SHA1` or `HMAC` instance, like this:

```
Algorithm.HMAC.hash(someText, sb);
```

or pass around `EncryptionAlgo` instances, like this:

```
EncryptionAlgo algo = Algorithm.SHA1;
```

Comment: Well, `Algorithm` *could* contain static instances of both `Sha1` and `Hmac` and return one or the other, assuming that both those classes implement the `EncryptionAlgo` interface.  But making `Algorithm` *itself* implement the interface seems better, since it avoids the need to call `getInstance()`.  An enum instance is already a static singleton, so it's stilly to use one just to look up *another* static singleton.

Comment: Also, SHA1 and HMAC are hash functions, not encryption algorithms.  The `EncryptionAlgo` interface would be better named something like `HashFunction`.

Comment: You don't actually need the interface.  You can just have the method on the enum type directly.