# Java generic enum parameter where the enums have methods

Tags: java, enums

I have 2 or more enums with the same methods in each. I need to use all these enums to validate a message in another class. Each enum have the same methods. I understand how to pass an enum as a generic parameter but I don't believe it is then possible to call that enum's method in the method that receives the enum as a generic enum.

Comment: Share some code

Comment: Use interfaces. Enums can implement interfaces.

Comment: [Why would an Enum implement an Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709593/why-would-an-enum-implement-an-interface)

Answer (score 1):

Just like other classes, `enum`s can implement interfaces.

```
interface CanThing {
    void doThing(); 
}

enum Validate implements CanThing {
    ONE_THING {
        @Override
        public void doThing() {
            System.out.println("One thing");
        }
    },
    OTHER_THING;

    // Default.
    @Override
    public void doThing() {
        System.out.println("No thing");
    }
}

public void doAThing(CanThing thing) {
    thing.doThing();
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    for (CanThing t: Validate.values()) {
        doAThing(t);
    }
}
```