# Compiler thinks that calling constructor with arg.getClass().cast(arg) is recursive, althought it wrong

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

I have an interface `Commodity`, that is a supertype of `Item` and `Consumable` enums.
Also, there is a class `Option` with multiple constructors:

```java
class Option{
    Option(Item c,int price){. . .}
    Option(Consumable c,int price){. . .}
    Option(Commodity c,int price){
        this(c.getClass()!=Commodity.class?c.getClass().cast(c):Item.EMPTY,price);
    }
}
}
```

Compiler thinks, that this will lead to an infinite recursion, but it obviously won't.

> `Recursive constructor invocation Option(Commodity, int)`

How to say him "Shut up, guy, I know, what I am doing!"?

Comment: Compilers are (almost?) never wrong about this sort of thing. You don't need to tell it to shut up, you need to (better) tell it what you meant.

Comment: Think about what the type of the whole `? :` expression is here. It'll use the combined type to resolve a single call.

Comment: This `c.getClass()!=Commodity.class` is fishy. `getClass` returns the actual runtime class, so it will never be `Commodity`. This condition is always true

Comment: "but it obviously won't" - you may wish to think about what's "obvious".

Comment: @Jorn, The problem here is that I need to call constructor, that corresponds to the type of an argument. To avoid huge expression like `A instanceof B?(B)arg : A instanceof C?(C)arg : ....` (for each subclass) I've decided to use handy statement like `arg.getClass.cast(arg)`. Isn't it called polymorphism and used in many places?

Comment: @TechoftheAbsence It may sound clever, but if it doesn't work... The problem is that the target constructor call is chosen at *compile* time, so you just cannot do it this way.

Comment: By the way, a *proper* polymorphic design wouldn't need separate constructors for each subclass. The differentiating logic should be in the `Commodity` subclasses, not in the `Option` class.

Comment: If I had pass on instance of class `Item` (in a variable of type `Commodity`), should `getClass()` return `Item`? Or am I fundamentally wrong?

Comment: You would be correct *at runtime*. But the constructor call is resolved at *compile time*. I suppose you *could* call that "fundamentally wrong" if you so choose ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, the compiler isn't actually wrong here. Let's look at the separate parts of your code:

I'm going to assume that both `Item` and `Consumable` extend `Commodity`.

`Item.EMPTY`: We can assume this is of type `Item`.

`c.getClass().cast(c)`: This does nothing. It's always going to be of type `Commodity`.

`c.getClass()!=Commodity.class?c.getClass().cast(c):Item.EMPTY` will then resolve to the common supertype. That's `Commodity`.

The compiler has no choice but to choose the `Commodity` overload, and that's what makes it a recursive call.

All in all, what you are trying to do is call a different constructor overload based on a conditional. That's simply not possible in Java. Instead, you should make a factory method:

```
static Option create(Commodity commodity, int price) {
  return commodity instanceof Consumable ? new Option((Consumable) commodity, price) : new Option(Item.EMPTY, price);
}
```

Comment: So... Is there a way to avoid that god-awfull (when used for many more than 2 classes) if-else-like construction? Can I replace it with something shorter and simpler?

Comment: Probably. This logic feels like it should be in the `Commodity` subclasses, not in the `Option` class.

Comment: Then how to organise it in subclasses?

Comment: You haven't shown the different constructor implementations, so I can't know that. But I'd start by defining a method in the `Commodity` class and overriding or implementing it in the subclasses.

Comment: What method are you concretely talking about? Do you suggest placing constructors' code into some method?

Comment: What should I do, If `Commodity` is an interface, and `Item` & `Consumable` are enums? No methods can be defined (except too restricted ones with default keyword).

Comment: @TechoftheAbsence Enums can implement interfaces. Check [Why would an Enum implement an Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709593/why-would-an-enum-implement-an-interface), there are lot of examples in the answers.

Comment: @Chaosfire, yes they are, but then we'r unable to define or redefine a method.

Comment: @TechoftheAbsence Yes, we can do that, as I said, check the examples in the answers.

Comment: Well, thanks for new information, but what method should I realize there, If I am using `Option` constructors for changing design of that `Option` (extends `JComponent`)?