# Java Default Constructor Issue - What Actually Constitutes a 'Default Constructor'?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

I am working on Java practice questions and came across this :

Given:

```
class X {}

class Y {Y () {}}

class Z {z(int i ) {} }
```

Which class has a default constructor?

**A.** X only

**B.** Y only

**C.** Z only

**D.** X and Y

**E.** Y and Z

**F.** X and Z

**G.** X, Y and Z

I would say that the correct answer would be A, because class X is the only class without any explicitly defined constructor. My peer is saying that it would be G, because a what constitutes a default constructor is when you actually change values within the constructor body.

We've done some research and answers seem to differ when it comes to what a default constructor actually IS (at this level).

Can anyone provide an answer and logical explanation here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it `z(int i)` or `Z(int i)`?

Answer (score 9):

> My peer is saying that it would be G, because a what constitutes a default constructor is when you actually change values within the constructor body.

I would say your peer is wrong here, at the language level. [Section 8.8.9 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) *only* uses the term "default constructor" to mean "the constructor provided by the compiler if no constructor is explicitly specified".

I wish this were spelled out more explicitly - and I also wish that C# used the same terminology :(

Comment: +1 `Z` doesn't compile unless `z` should be read as `Z`

Comment: Thank you - also answer key says it is G, which means answer key is wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor

Comment: @EricT: Yes, that's clearly incorrect. Sigh.