# When creating an overloaded constructor, is a default constructor needed?

Tags: java

Just learning about them now and very new to java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor

Comment: @Makoto: That's simply not true. If you provide a *different* constructor, the compiler won't supply a parameterless one.

Comment: @Makoto From the link provided by NPE: *if you define at least one constructor, the default constructor is not generated*, and then check the best reference for the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  If any constructor is defined, there is no default constructor (i assume you mean no-argument constructor) unless you explicitly define it.  If no constructors are defined, then the default constructor is implied.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a constructor for your object then it will be used. If you don't call it java won't call the no-argument constructor thus you have to provide it yourself.

I think the official java documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) provides some examples which are simple to understand.