# Why do I need to have a constructor in this Java generic subclass?

Tags: java, subclass

I am working with Java generics. Here is a code example followed by the question.

```
public class Test<T extends Comparable<T>>  {

    T data;

    public Test(T data) {

           this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {

            return this.data;
    }
}

class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Test<T> {
        //if I remove this constructor, code will not compile
    public MyClass(T data) {

        super(data);
    }
}
```

In MyClass, if I do not have the constructor I get the following compile time error:

```
Implicit super constructor Test<T>() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

Why does the compiler make me do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with generics, in point of fact.

Comment: As soon as you declare a constructor, the implied no-argument constructor no longer exists. Also, constructors are not inherited. This is fairly basic Java language rules, it's unrelated to generics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java default constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

Comment: That link was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @user3270407 By the way, simply removing the `super(data)` call is sufficient to produce a compiler error; even with your subclass constructor still there.

Comment: Ok and after looking at and reading the possible duplicate question you pointed out that makes total sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This problem is not related to generics.)

`Test` does not have a default (i.e. no argument) constructor.

Therefore your child class needs to call explicitly the single constructor that you've provided in `Test`. (The compiler cannot figure out what to do due to this ambiguity - how would it know which argument(s) to pass - so it raises a compile-time error.)

Comment: Oh ok. Do you know why that is?

Comment: It's part of the Java Language Specification (JLS). C++ has the same property. The compiler-generated default constructor is automatically deleted if you supply one with arguments.

Comment: Because the default constructor for `MyClass` -- or any class without an explicit constructor -- is always a no-arg constructor that just calls `super()`, which doesn't actually work here.

Comment: @user3270407 due to ambiguity, there is no way for the VM to know what to pass as an argument elsewise.

Comment: @user3270407 As soon as you declare a constructor in a class, it doesn't have a default constructor anymore.

Comment: Ok. thank you guys for the helpful feedback and clarification.