# constructors between super and sub classes in java

Tags: java, constructor

When I created a subclass that have two constructors, I need to define a constructor `SuperClass(int m)` because my second constructor from the sub class is calling it `super()`. This is the part I understand. But the code will not compile unless I define another constructor in the SuperClass like `SuperClass(){}`, not `SuperClass(int m, int n){}` . Why?

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    int i,j,k;
    public SubClass(int m, int n){
        this.i = m;
        this.j=n;
    }
    public SubClass(int m){
        super(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a default constructor if you have one which accepts arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java default constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl could you elaborate? why not SuperClass(int m, int n){} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public SubClass(int m, int n){
    this.i = m;
    this.j=n;
}
```

In the constructor above it is implied that a super class no-args constructor exists. It is the same as:

```
public SubClass(int m, int n){
    super(); // This was implied.
    this.i = m;
    this.j=n;
}
```

The other case is this:

```
public SubClass(int m){
    super(m);
}
```

Here you declare the you are using a super class constructor that takes one argument `m`.

So, basically your super class must declare two constructors to make the code work:

```
SuperClass() {
    // The default constructor
}

SuperClass(int m) {
    // one arg constructor...
}
```

However, if you specify the following super class constructor:

```
SuperClass(int m, int n){}
```

Then you could rewrite your sub class constructor like this:

```
public SubClass(int m, int n){
    super(m, n);
}
```

[This article from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) explains the usage of constructors very well!

Answer (score 1):

One of your SubClass constructors does not call a constructor of the super class.  If you do not specify a super constructor the JDK will assume the default constructor.  If the super class has no default constructor then it cannot compile.

Answer (score 0):

In java when you explicitly define any constructor to a class. The default constructor is no more available and you need to define your the default constructor again.

And in subclass's constructor, by default the very first implicit statement will the `super()` in case you have not explicitly called any other super constructor

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    int i,j,k;
    public SubClass(int m, int n){
        super() //implicit
        this.i = m;
        this.j=n;
    }
    public SubClass(int m){
        super(m);
    }
}
```