# Can I define `default constructor` in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, theory

My question below is rather theoretical then practical.
From many Java resources available online  I found out that a `default constructor` for a class has below specification:

1. takes no arguments
2. has no `throws` clauses
3. has an empty body

Java language [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) does not provide definition for `default constructor`, it only states that

> If a class (definition) contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor is implicitly declared (by a compiler).

Please notice that wording `implicitly declared` implies that the explicitly defined default constructor is possible. Lets consider below class:

```
public class Point {
  private int x;
  private int y;

  public int getX() { return x; } 
  public int getY() { return y; } 
}
```

For this class the compiler will generate below default constructor:

```
public Point() {
  super();
}
```

My question is, if I as a programmer would implement a constructor as `public Point() { }` could it be called a `default constructor` for above class Point? If not, then can any explicitly defined constructor be considered a `default constructor`? I appreciate the answer from somebody that is an expert or absolutely sure on this topic.

Comment: The JLS does define the what a default constructor is. See section 8.8.9 of the Java 8 Language Specification.

Comment: If you believe this is not a duplicate; please let us know why "It's not a valid answer" isn't a reason.  What's not valid? What would be valid?

Comment: re-opening due to the edit that states why this is different from other questions that it's supposedly a duplicate of. someone who has more experience with Java will have to doublecheck me. Re-close and point to the duplicate if it's still a duplicate of something.

Answer (score 5):

If you **explicitly** define any constructor, then it cannot be a **default** constructor, even if you code one that is exactly equivalent to default constructor generated by the compiler. Default, here, means in the absence of any action by you the programmer.

**UPDATE: OP wants an answer based on evidence**

**Compiler Rules from Section 13.4.12 Method and Constructor Declarations (JLS8):**

1. If you declare no constructors in your class, then a default constructor is generated by the compiler.

> Evidence: If the source code for a non-inner class contains no declared constructors, then a default constructor with no parameters is implicitly declared (§8.8.9).

2. If **you do declare one or more constructors** in your class, even if, it is a no-arg constructor and so akin to the compiler generated default constructor, **your explicit constructor** will replace the compiler generated default constructor. To stress this further, your explicit no-arg constructor which is equivalent to the compiler generated one is not the compiler generated one.

> Evidence: Adding one or more constructor declarations to the source code of such a class will prevent this default constructor from being implicitly declared, effectively deleting a constructor, unless one of the new constructors also has no parameters, thus replacing the default constructor.

Comment: Please notice that the 'evidence' text pretends only to implicitly defined `default constructor`. There is nothing about explicitly defined one in it. Therefore it is not an answer to my question: can I explicitly define `default constructor` in Java?

Comment: Are you just trying to be pedantic or is there some real value behind your question? You are now going into the realms of the meaning of certain words in the English language! As I have mentioned in my original answer and backed by the evidence, YOU CANNOT EXPLICITLY DEFINE A DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR. It is a MEANINGLESS statement in Java. You can explicitly define a constructor which looks and behaves like the compiler generated default constructor BUT it will NEVER BE CONSIDERED A **DEFAULT** CONSTRUCTOR. It will considered just a user-defined constructor. Do you get it now?

Comment: Can I ask you if you understand what you read? It is clearly there : default constructor from being `implicitly` declared

Comment: Let me explain this for you clearly. The first point above relates to the case when no constructor is declared at all so the compiler implicitly declares one. OK? But you are asking about creating an **explicit** one, which the second point addresses. In the English language and in this context, explicit means something which you are doing directly and in this case **you are declaring a constructor which looks and behaves like a default constructor**. However, the second piece of evidence tells you that even if you do that, that constructor...

Comment: ... is not considered to be **THE DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR*** since the compiler one is **REPLACED**. Do you understand now? **THEREFORE, YOU CANNOT CREATE AN EXPLICIT DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR**. You can create an explicit constructor which looks and behaves like a default constructor BUT it won't be considered as the default constructor.