# Does Java create a default constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

When we have a class like this which doesn't have any constructor:

```
public class F {
    public void sum() {
        System.out.println("print it");
    }
```

How does the `main` method create an object of this class? Does the object already have a constructor?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F obj = new F();
        obj.sum();
    }
}
```

Does Java have a default constructor like this:

```
public class F() {
}
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor).

Answer (score 6):

A default, no argument constructor is created for every class for which *no other constructor is defined*.

This constructor has no body, and only performs the implicit call to `super();`, which is the same behavior seen in an explicitly created constructor.