# How to call a static method in Java?

Tags: java

Here i have a class named `FirefoxPhDriver`

```
public class FirefoxPhDriver extends AbstractWebPhDriver {

    public static FirefoxPhDriver newInstance(
            PhDriverIngredients ingredients) {
        FirefoxPhDriver pd = new FirefoxPhDriver();

        if (pd.verify(ingredients)) {
            return pd;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

As i new to java am not sure how can i call this `newInstance` method in another class

i tried

```
FirefoxPhDriver drvr = new FirefoxPhDriver(ingrdients)
```

But am getting the constuctor FirefoxPhDriver is not visible

Comment: your question is "Call a method in another package in java". But in your post you are calling method in same class.

Answer (score 4):

It's just `FirefoxPhDriver drvr = FirefoxPhDriver.newIstance(ingrdients)`.

(Because `newInstance` is a static method you don't need to create an instance of `FirefoxPhDriver` to access the method (so no `new FirefoxPhDriver(...)`).)

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `FirefoxPhDriver drv = FirefoxPhDriver.newInstance(ingrdients)`

Answer (score 1):

You actually have no Constructor defined in your FirefoxPhDriver class, but the [default Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor).

But you have a Method defined

> public static FirefoxPhDriver newInstance(PhDriverIngredients ingredients)

This method creates a new Instance of the FirefoxPhDriver class.

You can use it like that:

```
FirefoxPhDriver drvr = FirefoxPhDriver.newInstance(ingredients);
```

Answer (score 0):

`newInstance()` method is static method in `FirefoxPhDriver` class. We can call static members along with Classname.

Use this:

```
 FirefoxPhDriver.newInstance(ingrdients);
```

If you want to call methods from other class we should declare those methods as either public or protected or default. We cannot call Private members from other class.