# Why do I get a 'constructor is undefined` error?

Tags: java

Why would the following code yield a compilation error (The constructor `AA()` is undefined)? Shouldn't it call a default constructor?

```
public class A{
    public A(){ }
}

public class AA extends A{
    public AA(int aa){ }
}

public class C{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a= new AA();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does AA have other constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will only add a default constructor to a `class` if there is no constructor in the `class` which is not the case for `AA`.

[**8.8.9 Default Constructors** **(Java language specification)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared

Answer (score 0):

You write

```
A a= new AA(); // try to invoke default constructor
```

But there is no [*default*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor) constructor in class `AA` because you write your own constructor

```
public AA(int aa){ }
```

So try this:

```
int someInteger = 1;
A a= new AA(someInteger);
```