# Which of these classes has a default constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

Which of these classes has a default constructor?  I'm thinking just A but am I wrong?

```
class A {}
class B {B() {}}
class C {C(int j) {}}
```

Comment: Why are you thinking that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java default constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. A default constructor is, by definition, created when no constructor is defined. Since `A` does not have a constructor defined it will have a default constructor created for it.

Technically speaking, you could say `B` has a default constructor since a parameter-less constructor is what would be created if none is defined.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9

Comment: Could you please add a reference to the "definition", might be helpful.

Comment: Added the closest thing I could find in the java documentation.

Comment: please update your reference to point to the official language specification instead of a tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9

Comment: @MWiesner Updated. Thanks for digging that up!

Answer (score 0):

Precisely.

Class `A` has a default constructor because you're not providing any constructor for the class. The compiler, therefore, automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass (in this case the Object class). The second class, Class `B`, is providing a no-argument constructor, but it is not default as the compiler is not providing it for you.