# Creating a Constructor with Parameter

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

this is probably a silly question, but I cant get my program to run.
I have to:

> Add a constructor to Hero that only takes a World as a parameter. Do not do anything in the constructor except set the World instance variable to the parameter passed in.

so far I have

```
public Hero(World world){
    this.world = world;
}
```

Is this right? Have been trying to call world later on in my program, but it isn't working.

Comment: What error do you get, please provide a *reproducible* example together with compiler/runtime output.

Comment: Are you calling the constructor like: `Hero heroVar = new Hero(world)`?

Comment: my compiler is saying it 'Can not find symbol'

Comment: how is your Hero class defined ?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? we need to see the msgs!!!

Comment: @J.Doe: please provide full source code. Have you defined a class `World` (in a file called `World.java`)?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed the way to define a constructor that takes as input a parameter.

A problem you might have overlooked is that when **calling the constructor**, you have to feed it a value. If you for instance have defined a class `Hero`:

```
public class Hero {

    private World world;

    public Hero (World world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

}
```

You **cannot** longer construct a `Hero` with:

```
Hero hero = new Hero();
```

Indeed, the `new Hero();` **expects a `World`**. You can for instance first construct a `World` and feed it to the hero:

```
World world = new World();
Hero hero = new Hero(world);
```

You also have to **define a class `World`** (in a file named `World.java`). For instance this stub:

```
public class World {

}
```

(If you do not provide a constructor yourself, Java will define a [default constructor itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4488716/67579)).

Depending on how you compile your project (using an IDE, using the command line,...) you sometimes need to add this file to your project yourself, or compile it with:

```
javac Hero.java World.java
```

(and perhaps other `.java` files)

Answer (score 0):

It is true that java provides a default no-parameter constructor when you don't define any constructor in your code but when you explicitly define a constructor which takes in some parameters, java doesn't provide the default constructor. Hence, you need to define the default no-parameter constructor here.

```
public Hero(){

}
```