# Java three classes hierarchy

Tags: java

I've been reading book algorithms on Java by Robert Lafore. And there is an problem - Object sorting. So there are three classes which make hierarchy. In book it is fine working but in Eclipse I have problem "Implicit super constructor Person() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor".
What shall I do with extentions classes, or what shall I change to make this code run? Please help. Thank you.

```
class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String last, String first, int a) {
        lastName = last;
        firstName = first;
        age = a;
    } 

    public void displayPerson() {
        System.out.print("Last name: " + lastName);
        System.out.print(". First name: " + firstName);
        System.out.println(". Age: " + age);
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Next class extends person.

```
public class ArrayInObj extends Person  {

    private Person a[];
    private int nElems;

    public ArrayInObj(int max) {        // Here is the problem
        a = new Person[max];
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(String last, String first, int age) {
        a[nElems] = new Person(last, first, age);
    }

    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
            a[i].displayPerson();
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    public void insertionSort( ) {
        int in, out;

        for (out = 1; out < nElems; out++) {
            Person temp = a[out];
            in = out;

            while (in > 0 && a[in-1].getLast().compareTo(temp.getLast()) > 0) {
                a[in] = a[in -1];
                --in;
            }
            a[in] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And the main class with main function.

```
public class ObjectSort extends ArrayInObj {

    public ObjectSort(int max) {
        super(max);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maxSize = 10;
        ArrayInObj arr = new ArrayInObj(maxSize);

        arr.insert("Evans", "Patty", 24);
        arr.insert("Smith", "Lorainne", 37);
        arr.insert("Yee", "Tom", 43);
        arr.insert("Adams", "Henry", 63);
        arr.insert("Hashimoto", "Sato", 21);

        System.out.println("Before sorting: ");
        arr.display();

        arr.insertionSort();

        System.out.println("After sorting: ");
        arr.display();

    }

}
```

Comment: define no-arg constructor in Person call like `public Person(){}` I would question is ArrayObj really a person?

Comment: You have a class ``ArrayInObj`` that is used as a container for multiple instances of ``Person``. As such, it should not extend ``Person``. Remove the inheritance (by removing ``extends Person``) and you dont have to worry about that error anymore.

Comment: @f1sh, +1. The question is a typical sample of inheritance misuse. Probably it's enough to use `List<Person>` here. If author needs a tree of persons (each person needs to have list of related persons), it should be done in a different manner by implementing type agnostic generic data structure like `MyTree<T>`, then a type specific tree of persons could be created: `new MyTree<Person>()`.

Comment: Is this an example in a book (I highly doubt that)? ArrayInObj is certainly not a Person. Why does it inherit from Person?

Comment: You have transcribed the code incorrectly. There is no inheritance among these three classes in the Lafore book. Recommend closing as a typo.

Comment: Yes in book there are no inheritance. Sorry that I made this thread. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical reason why you are getting this error is that the only constructor of `ArrayInObj` implicitly calls the constructor of its superclass as follows:

```
public ArrayInObj(int max) {
    /* this gets implicitly added and fails to compile */
    super();
    a = new Person[max];
    nElems = 0;
}
```

To fix the compile error, you can either explicitly call the superclass's existing constructor or define a zero-argument constructor for `Person`.

Reading your code I get the impression that the correct solution would be to remove the `extends Person` from `ArrayInObj`'s definition. Ask yourself: Is a `ArrayInObj` a `Person`? No, it seems to be a container for an array of `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayInObj` is extending `Person`, and in the constructor for `ArrayInObj`, it is implicitly calling the `Person` constructor `super()` (by not explicitly calling a different `super()`).  But, the `Person` class does not have a zero-argument constructor.  Either explicitly call a `Person` constructor that is defined, `super(a,b,c)`, or do not have `ArrayInObj extends Person`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities:

1. you add an constructor `Person()` to your Person class
2. you call the existing constructor with `super(last, first, a)` as first call in your ArrayInObj classes constructor
3. Is your ArrayInObj-class realy a Person? Does not look like it is. Remove `extends Person`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to provide a default constructor in your Person class, so that the ArrayInObj class may use it.

You will also benefit from reading about constructors in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html, or regarding default constructors this site [Java default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor).