# Details about implicit constructor in java with example

Tags: java, class, constructor, coupling

I want a clarification for this statement related to implicit constructor in Java. I read this statement in [an article](http://www.ajol.info/index.php/wajiar/article/download/91389/80885) but I need more details about it and an example to understand it.

The statement is: *An implicit constructor call is made when a variable of type B is defined and instantiated in class A, for example, B b = new B()*.

Comment: Please include at least a link to the article for context.

Comment: http://www.ajol.info/index.php/wajiar/article/download/91389/80885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basically saying that any class that is instantiated has an implicit constructor:

```
public class B {

    //constructor       
    public B() {
        //implicity constructor
    }

}

public class A {

    //constructor       
    public A() {
         Bb = new B(); //calls the constructor inside B during setup even if the constructor method does not exist within B an implicit constructor is made
    }

}
```

> The default constructor is the no-argument constructor automatically
>   generated unless you define another constructor. It initialises any
>   uninitialised fields to their default values. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

When B is instantiated from A this constructor is called during its creation basically. For more specific details you should really ask in a different exchange than stack-overflow maybe try the programmers section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ,,this is a good answer for my question.