# Constructor cannot be applied

Tags: java, android, class, sqliteopenhelper

i was doing this tutorial on ***Android Studio Development Essentials 6th Edition***, the tutorial was about SQLiteDatase so i wrote evrything but i kept on getting an error whenever i try calling the Product Constructor everything is correct on the book but i cant get it right, this is the find Product Constructor and my Product class.

***Find product***

```
  public Product findProduct(String productname) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " = " + productname + ";";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Product product = new Product();// Cannot be applied
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        product.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        product.setProductName(cursor.getString(1));
        product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        product = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return product;
}
```

**My Product Class**

```
public class Product {
private int id;
private String ProductName;
private int Quantity;

public Product(int _id, String _productname, int _quantity) {
    this.id = _id;
    this.ProductName = _productname;
    this.Quantity = _quantity;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return ProductName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.ProductName = productName;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return Quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.Quantity = quantity;
}
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: As you have an overloaded constructor, you MUST add an empty constructor to the Product class.

Comment: can you show me were to add please... thank you @RajithaSiriwardena

Comment: There is **no need** to be *empty* - only *without parameters*. - @Rajitha Siriwardena

Comment: @MarianD Oops my bad. Let me rephrase...you MUST add a constructor with empty params, aka a default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public Product(int _id, String _productname, int _quantity) {
```

is the *only* constructor in you `Product` class definition (you don't have any others), so you have to call its constructor **with these 3 parameters** - instead of

```
    Product product = new Product();// Cannot be applied
```

use something as

```
    Product product = new Product(132, "Wheel", 1000);
```

> Another solution:

**Add another constructor** in your `Product` class *besides existing one*, e. g. an empty one:

```
    public Product() {}
```

(it may be located before or after your existing one).

Comment: i know that's how the constructor works am trying to get the data from a cursor not add it by myself

Comment: You may construct an object and then *change* its properties from a cursor, or add a constructor without parameters - i will extend my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

If You created Your own constructor, the default one is not generated. Please take a look at [Java default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor) 
Regards