# A elegant way to implement ID on a abstract class

Tags: java, oop

I have an abstract class. I want that every instance has a unique ID. I have implemented:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass{

    static AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();
    private int id;

    public MyAbstractClass() {
        id = nextId.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {

       public MyClass(){
             super();
       }
}
```

This approach works except the part there is nothing forcing the subclass to call the constructor.

Is there a way to implement a global ID for an abstract class?

Comment: If I have understood things correctly, classes always implicitly call the parameterless constructor of their parent class. `super();` is the first thing that happens in the constructor of the child class.

Comment: I have edited the question, providing more context.

Comment: My comment was an answer to your *"there is nothing forcing the subclass to call the constructor"*, telling you that there is in fact something forcing it to do precisely that.

Comment: Is it wrong to suggest the use of an abstract factory design pattern for this situation?

Comment: Completely unrelated too, `nextId` should also be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is nothing forcing the subclass to call the constructor.

There is nothing you can do **to stop the subclass from calling `super()`** unless parent constructors are built hierarchically wrong.

By "hierarchically wrong", I meant there is a parent constructor that isn't based on its no-argument constructor. For instance,

```
public MyAbstractClass() {
    id = nextId.incrementAndGet();
}

public MyAbstractClass(String s) {
    // ignores to call this();
}
```

Otherwise, any child will eventually call `super()`, and, thus, trigger your id initialisation.

Comment: Did you mean the abstract class having more than one constructor?

Comment: Is it still called *default constructor* when you've implemented it with your own code (i.e. no longer default)?

Comment: @MatheusPopstdeCampos If it had, you would need to make sure each constructor calls the default one (`this();` as the first line in the body of a parent constructor)

Comment: @Gendarme I am not sure I got you correctly. Any child constructor will call a parent constructor. Any parent constructor will call the default constructor. Does it make more sense?

Comment: I'll rephrase. Is the parameterless constructor (which always exists) called *default constructor*  even when you implement it (override it?) in your code (since it's arguably no longer default)? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488766/5221346) suggests that it isn't.

Comment: @Gendarme edited to "no-argument constructor", it's more accurate, is it?