# Why does IntelliJ want me to construct an empty constructor?

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

[intelliJ message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRlrH.png)

I am new to Java and I understand constructors(I guess), but why does my code does not work until I construct an empty constructor? When I already have a constructor with parameters etc of that class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

Comment: it seems that you declared a constructor taking a number of arguments. so the no-arguments constructor is no longer available. You need to either declare a no-arg constructor, or to pass in the required arguments

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have a constructor with no argument at your class. That's why when you are trying to create an instance using the no argument constructor it showing you the error.

Note that, If you don't define any constructor then the class have a default constructor with no parameter. But if you do declare a constructor then there is no default constructor, only the ones you define.

Hope this will clear your confusion.

Comment: I checked out a code from a tutorial which only had one constructor which was expecting few arguments. Everywhere in the code only that constructor was used. Even then I was getting error that can't access this class. So, when I added a no args constructor all errors went away. And now if I remove that no arg constructor, errors don't come now. Not sure, what caused those errors in the first place.