# What is the internal process behind that error "variable Y not initialized in the default constructor" in java?

Tags: java, static, final

I want to know about that error "**variable Y not initialized in the
 default constructor**" what happens internally...

```
static final int y;
public static void main(String[] as){
System.out.println(y);
}
```

1. I've used static variable not instance but sill i got.
2. Why it is only initilzed in **sameline** or **static block** .
3. What is the roll of **default constructor**.

Comment: final fields should be initialized before object creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'hve used static variable not instance but sill i got

It's not because of `static` keyword; it's because of `final` keyword which requires `y` to be initialized. If you remove the keyword, `final` from the declaration, it will compile without any problem.

> Why it is only initilzed in sameline or static block .

Again, if it has been declared as `final`, it has to be initialized with the declaration. Initializing it in a [static block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) won't work.

> What is the roll of default constructor.

Check [Java default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I've used static variable, not instance, but still I got `variable Y not initialized in the default constructor`.

The error is misleading. The default constructor part should be ignored. The rest of the error is correct.

> 2. Why it is only initialized in same line or static block.

It must be initialized before the class is put into service. Those are the only two places where you can do that, so it must be initialized in exactly one of them.

> 3. What is the role of default constructor.

As mentioned for #1, it has no role here.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you try to use variables before they have a value, you will usually get a **NullPointerException** telling you that this variable has no value except **null**.

**2.** You have "created" a constant which must be assigned before creating the object. That can be done in the static-block

```
static {
   //assignment - no logic here!
}
```

or directly at "create".

**3.** The **standard constructor** is only for **creating objects**, because there is no room for assignments or logic **(never logic in the constructor)**. Unless you change it.