# If a subclass has no constructor, and neither does the superclass, then why can I construct an instance of the subclass?

Tags: java, class, oop, constructor, subclass

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html:
"You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the **compiler will complain** if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does."

In the following code, class Goblin has no constructor. Neither does its superclass, Humanoid.

```
public class Humanoid {
    int weight;

    //public Humanoid() {
        //weight = 10;
    //}
}

class Goblin extends Humanoid {
    char armorColor;
}

class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Goblin grug = new Goblin();
        System.out.println(grug.armorColor);

        boolean isGrugAGoblin = false;
        isGrugAGoblin = (grug instanceof Goblin);
        System.out.println(isGrugAGoblin);
    }
}
```

I compiled and ran the above code successfully, despite the tutorial's claim that the compiler would complain.
The output was

```
true
```

I expected an error, like the tutorial claimed. Is the tutorial wrong?

Comment: The compiler will complain when the superclass `Humanoid` does not have a no-arg constructor. But it has one, so no complain here.

Comment: you yourself wrote/copied : "*The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.*" -- to have it complain, you *must* provide an one-or-more-argument constructor in `Humanoid`, so it does not get one provided automatically by the compiler

Comment: `Humanoid` gets a no-argument, default constructor by default, and then `Goblin` _also_ gets a no-argument, default constructor by default that calls `Humanoid`'s default constructor.  The tutorial is correct and Java is correct, it's your interpretation that's confused.

Comment: Isn’t the text clear? The compiler provides a default no-arg constructor for `Humanoid`. So when it does the same for `Goblin`,  the provided `Goblin` constructor calls the provided constructor of `Humanoid`. The tutorial is correct, it seems you just read it wrong and didn’t take the full meaning into account.

Comment: @user85421 You could provide that as an answer? It’s very helpful. (I searched for this question having been asked before, and though it probably has, if we can’t find it, I think the best thing we can do is answer it here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every class in Java inherits, ultimately, from [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html). That is why your class has methods such as [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()).

When you instantiate any class, an implicit call is made to its immediate superclass, and the immediate superclass of that, onwards to eventually reach `Object`.

In your case, `Humanoid` extends `java.lang.Object`.

> class Goblin has no constructor

Incorrect.

The class `Goblin` has no *explicit* constructor. It does have an *implicit* constructor. Think of it as the compiler writing the constructor on your behalf, behind your back.

For more info, see [this Answer by OrangeDog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488766/642706) to the Question, [*Java default constructor*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4488716/642706).

> Neither does its superclass, Humanoid

Ditto. `Humanoid` has an implicit default constructor.

For all the details, see Section [8.8.9. Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) of *Java Language Specification*.

Comment: Be aware that the compiler only writes an implicit no-arg constructor as long as you don't provide *any* constructor at all for that specific class. The moment you declare a custom constructor for eg initializing some object values there is no no-arg constructor provided by default anymore.

Comment: Learning that java doesn't offer an implicit constructor anymore if any explicit constructor is defined, is what cleared things up for me. Thanks. But I can't mark user85421's answer as correct. It seems to be a comment.