Unexpected output while dealing with hierarchies in Java
i was working on a school worksheet when i stumbled on this problem. I have the vehicle class as such:
public class Vehicle {
private static int idcouter = 0;

private int id;
private Condition condition;
private int price;

public Vehicle() {
    this.id = idcouter++;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.price = price;
}

public Condition getCondition() {
    return condition;
}

public void setCondition(Condition condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}}

And Truck as such:
public class Truck extends Vehicle {
private boolean trailer;

public Truck() {
    super();
    this.trailer = trailer;
}

@Override
public void setPrice(int price) {
    if (this.getCondition() == enums.Enums.Condition.NEW) {
        if (this.trailer) {
            int tempPrice = (int) (price * 0.95f);
            super.setPrice(tempPrice);
        } else {
            super.setPrice(price);
        }
    } else {
        int tempPrice = (int) (price * 0.85f);
        super.setPrice(tempPrice);
    }
}}

Given my main:
    Truck t1 = new Truck();
    Truck t2 = new Truck();
    Truck t3 = new Truck();
    t1.setPrice(200);
    t2.setPrice(200);
    t3.setPrice(200);
    
    t1.setCondition(enums.Enums.Condition.NEW);
    t1.setTrailer(true);
    
    t2.setCondition(enums.Enums.Condition.NEW);
    t2.setTrailer(false);
    
    t3.setCondition(enums.Enums.Condition.USED);
    t3.setTrailer(true);
    
    System.out.println("Price: " + t1.getPrice());
    System.out.println("Price: " + t2.getPrice());
    System.out.println("Price: " + t3.getPrice());

Why is my output:
Price: 170

For all the trucks 1,2 and 3.
It makes no sense, it should be overriding it. I did something similar with Car, a sub class of vehicle and it worked perfectly. I´ve tried different things but i can't understand what's happening. If anyone could share some information or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Sorry for that, added

It's because the value of the member variable trailer is false for all instance of Truck (t1,t2, t3). The method setPrice is called before the setTrailer is called.
The logic of setPrice will always see trailer as false which is the default value for a native boolean. If trailer would be of type Boolean the setPrice method would throw a NullPointerExcpetion for all calls of setPrice(200).
The assignments in the constructors of Truck and Vehicle are useless because the constructors have no arguments which could be assigned to this.xxxxx variables.

Hi, easterwood, on this scenario where the teacher only allows me to use methods to interact with objects should i not have a constructer then? and just let java take care of it with the default one? What's the most "correct" way of handling this example? And thanks for the help, i recently started learning.

Yes, you could completely remove your constructor code for Truck. The constructor for Vehicle seems necessary but only the part with idcounter.  (Other constructor parts you defined behave like the so called default constructor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor). A most "correct" neither exists. It's always "it depends" :) and as your teacher demands not to use constructors for setting initial values using setter seems to be adequate.

The only time t1.price gets set is when you call t1.setPrice(200). At that time, t1.condition is null, so it gets set to (int) (price * 0.85f), which is 170. Same thing applies to t2 and t3. Everything afterwards modifies the condition and the trailer members, but it doesn't magically alter the price.
If you want setCondition() etc to magically alter the price, only safe the base price and do the calculation when you're retrieving the price.
Btw: You might want to fix your constructors. As written, most lines in the constructors don't do anything. Don't you get a warning from your IDE? There is no condition parameter, so this.condition and condition refer to the same thing - which makes this.condition = condition; pointless. Same for the other assignments except from the id.

Hi, Soren, as i asked easterwood on this scenario, what's the most "correct" way of handling the constructer on this example? And thanks for the help
