# Singleton Controller Java

Tags: java, singleton, singleton-methods

I was reading about singletons the other day and thought to implement them in a project of mine, but I didn't like the way it seemed to flow logically, so I created what I'd call a controller class to manage the state of the singleton object. I want to make sure that the logic checks out though, and that I'm not inadvertently spawning off additional instances.

```
//Controller for SaveSystem, allows the class to be created once for the 
//duration of the application at the global level (believe this is called a 
//singleton pattern)

public class SaveSystemContr {
  private static SaveSystem saveSystemInstance;
  public SaveSystem GetSaveSystemData() {
    return saveSystemInstance;
  }

  public void SetSaveSystem(SaveSystem _saveSystem) {
    if(saveSystemInstance!=null) {
        saveSystemInstance=_saveSystem;
    }
  }

  public static SaveSystem getSaveSystemInstance(final FirebaseAuth _auth, final LoadProjFragment _LFP) {
    if(saveSystemInstance==null) {
        saveSystemInstance = new SaveSystem(_auth, _LFP);
    }

    return saveSystemInstance;
  }

  public SaveSystemContr() {} //THE WAY IS SHUT!
}
```

Edit* I do not view this as a duplicate of the question referenced, as that was a typical/standard implementation of a singleton, and this uses a different model altogether by utilizing a controller to manage the state of the singleton.

Comment: It's not supposed to be a singleton pattern directly, rather a controlling class that manages a single instance of another class. It seemed to make more sense to me at the time, but maybe it's unnecessary/problematic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singleton class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111768/singleton-class-in-java)

Comment: that appears to a typical singleton class, yes, but this one I implement as: 'SaveSystemContr SSC = new SaveSystemContr();'
'saveSystem = SSC.getSaveSystemInstance(auth, this);'

Comment: My question is: what problem are you trying to solve? Design patterns exist to solve specific design problems. What problem is this design solving?

Comment: If you're considering this kind of thing, it is not that far from having a Dependency injection framework manage your objects' scopes, DI lets you have singletons without the boilerplate of the controller and the ugliness of static references.

Comment: Good point Vince. I think I was primarily concerned with maintainability, it seemed like having this part of the code under my SaveSystem class would clutter it up. I tried to build that class as efficient as possible because it's complexity grows substantially because it deals with waterfall-esque queries (another term here...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make sure that the logic checks out though, and that I'm not inadvertently spawning off additional instances.

Looks like you can create as many instances as you want:

```
SaveSystemContr controller = new SaveSystemContr();

// Create instance 1
controller.SetSaveSystem(new SaveSystem(auth, lfp));

// Create instance 2
controller.SetSaveSystem(new SaveSystem(auth, lfp));

// ...
```

Why do you have a setter method if you only want 1 instance?

A very basic singleton will look like this:

```
public final class SaveSystemSingleton {
  // This class should only be accessed statically. Don't allow instance creation
  private SaveSystemSingelton() {}

  private static SaveSystem saveSystem;

  // Encapsulate creation logic. Passing in params is misleading because
  // all subsequent calls will do nothing with the params.
  public static SaveSystem get() {
    // If accessing from multiple threads do Double Check Locking instead!
    if (saveSystem == null) {
      saveSystem = new SaveSystem(new FirebaseAuth(), new LoadProjFragment());
    }
    return saveSystem;
  }
}
```

If you really need to pass in the params, define a separate static setter method, and throw an exception if it is called more than once or if `get()` is called without first calling the setter.

Also, you should check out dependency injection (e.g. [Dagger2](https://google.github.io/dagger/)), which makes creating instances of objects and scoping them clear and easy.

Comment: This seems to be what I was after. I like how it has an external class to manage an internal class. I do need to pass in the parameters, so I will be looking at the double locking mechanism you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor private and remove getters and setters :

```
    //Allows the OBJECT (not class) to be created once only    
    public class SaveSystem {

      private static SaveSystem saveSystemInstance;

      //make constructor private 
      private SaveSystem(final FirebaseAuth _auth, final LoadProjFragment _LFP) {
        //todo complete constructor
      }

      public static SaveSystem getSaveSystemInstance(final FirebaseAuth _auth, final LoadProjFragment _LFP) {
        if(saveSystemInstance==null) {
            saveSystemInstance = new SaveSystem(_auth, _LFP);
        }   
        return saveSystemInstance;
      } 
    }
```

As you see it can be applied on `SaveSystem` without a controller.