# Java private constructor with parameters

Tags: java, parameters, private-constructor

newbe question. Does it make any sense to have a private constructor in java with parameters?  Since a private constructor can only be accessed within the class wouldn't any parameters have to be instance variables of  that class?

Comment: good use case would be for the [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111768/singleton-class-in-java)

Comment: It's also useful for the builder pattern. If the builder is a nested subclass of the main class it can access the private constructor and use it to create objects.

Comment: You overlooked that a class can also have static methods that can access the private constructor. The actual values are therefore not restricted to instance variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are going to use that constructor in some method of your class itself and expose the method to other class like we do in the **singleton** pattern. One simple example of that would be like below :

```
public class MySingleTon {    
    private static MySingleTon myObj;
    private String creator;
    private MySingleTon(String creator){
         this.creator = creator;
    }
    public static MySingleTon getInstance(String creator){
        if(myObj == null){
            myObj = new MySingleTon(creator);
        }
        return myObj;
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){
        MySingleTon st = MySingleTon.getInstance("DCR");
    } 
}
```

Comment: what if instead of mySingleTon we had a MyUtility something like java's Math class.  In that case does it still make sense?

Comment: Your actual example could be improved. You pass a parameter in `getInstance("DCR")`  but if you reinvoke the method with a new parameter such as `getInstance("RCD")` it will not be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have multiple `public` constructors with the same variable to assign to a specific field or that you need to perform the same processing, you don't want to repeat that in each public constructor but you want to delegate this task to the common `private` constructor.
So defining parameters to achieve that in the `private` constructor makes sense.

For example :

```
public class Foo{

   private int x;
   private int y;

   public Foo(int x, int y, StringBuilder name){
      this(x, y);
      // ... specific processing
   } 

   public Foo(int x, int y, String name){
      this(x, y);
      // ... specific processing
   } 

   private Foo(int x, int y){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   } 
}
```